# Extjs - Use ColumnHeaderGroup dynamically 

Tags: extjs, header, grid, grouping

Is there a way to use ColumnHeaderGroup automatically by the json data returning from the server?

I am looking for a way not to deal with it over and over in every grid...
Looking to simple it up.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a plugin so not really. Plugins are usually used at startup so you would have to remove the grid and add the grid from a containing component.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can you the grouping plugin in Extjs 4.2 , for refrence please see the examples

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/example , also you can chnage the grouping at runtime using stores methods

```
store.clearGrouping( );

store.group( groupers, [direction] );
```